# Expose the same set collection with two properties

Tags: c#, .net, generics, covariance, typing

<sup>**Note: Please don't value this question on its current state. Once I could fix my underlying issue I realized that I would have a very hard time trying to rephrase this question to really reflect what motivated it and what was the resolution. Anwyay, I'll try to rephrase it during the next days so it can be useful for future visitors and the answerer might have a chance to adapt the answer. Even my auto-answer wasn't reflecting the issue so it can be useful to the community...**</sup>

Let's say I've an interface like this:

```
public interface IHasMany<T>
{
      ISet<T> Items { get; }
}
```

And a class implements it as follows:

```
public class X : IHasMany<IWhatever>
{
     public ISet<Whatever> Whatevers { get; } = new HashSet<Whatever>();
     ISet<IWhatever> IHasMany<IWhatever>.Items { get; }
}
```

Since a collection generic type can't be *covariant* (I understand the background of *why it's prevented by design*), there's no easy path to both expose a set of some given interface implementations and a set of the same implementations typed as the interface at once.

I'm scratching my head in order to find out a solution on which ideally I wouldn't need to implement some kind of synchronization or change tracking to maintain two different collections...

Note that `IHasMany<T>.Items` must still be writable, otherwise it would be as easy as typing it as `IEnumerable<IWhatever>` and go forward...

Comment: Maybe you have two interfaces, the covariant interface with only convariance allowed and a contravariant interface with only contravariance allowed. From there you can have an interface which inherits both but the generic parameter is invariant

Comment: @CallumLinington If I'm not mistaken about the understanding of your approach, I believe it has a problem: either `ICollection<T>` or `ISet<T>` aren't covariant nor contravariant :/

Comment: I would argue that `ICollection<T>` and `ISet<T>` are actually covariant by nature because `IEnumerable` of which they both implement is covariant. If you look at the implementations they only do covariant operations.

Comment: @CallumLinington No they're not.  Both have a `Add` method, that means you pass the generic type in, co-variant only allows you to pass the type out.

Comment: Why do you want to do this in the first place?  I'm guessing there's a problem you're trying to solve with this and there's actually a different design choice you could make. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @juharr Possibly, I need to think about an alternative to this design, but I've thrown the issue here to see if I was missing something...

Comment: @juharr Finally I got to solve the problem myself, I've just added an answer. As everyone can check there, I was mistaken or crazy about the `IHasMany<T>` interface... I had the solution just in front of my face lol

Answer (score 5):

C# doesn't prevent your set from being covariant because the C# team didn't bother to figure out how to implement it.  Rather, it's not possible in C# because it's conceptually not possible.  You simply can't treat an `ISet<Whatever>` as if it's an `ISet<IWhatever>` because *you can add items to an `ISet<IWhatever>` that aren't of type `Whatever`*, and if the actual object is an `ISet<Whatever>`, then it's not allow to add items that aren't of type `Whatever`.

You can have a property of type `IReadOnlySet<IWhatever>` and make that covariant, but since you want to have a mutable set, there's no way to make it work.  You'll have to have your actual underlying set be a set of `IWhatever` objects, or have `X` implement `IHasMany<Whatever>` rather than `IHasMany<IWhatever>`, since it is only the former's contract that you actually want it to fulfill, not the latter's.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer It's the answer to your question.  It's certainly not a comment.  I also specifically mention what you posted as "an answer" as one of the things that you probably should have been doing, even though your "answer" actually doesn't answer your own question, as it doesn't do what your question asks it to do, and as such should probably just be a comment.

Comment: No, your answer is *not* an answer to your question.  It doesn't answer the question that you asked.  Had you actually asked a question that was representative of your actual problem, rather than explicitly stating that you couldn't use solutions that would actually solve your problem, then answers such as yours that happen to solve your problem but that *your question rejected as options* would actually have been answers.  This is why you need to be very careful about how you phrase your question, and what you ask for.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Do I think that it's a good idea that you posted an incorrect answer that doesn't actually answer your question instead of accepting a correct answer just because you didn't ask the question that you wanted to ask?  No, not really.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Your question poses no problem for which there could be an "alternate approach" to.  You asked how to make an invariant interface covariant.  That's it.  And the answer to that question is that "you can't".  Had you actually presented the real problem that you had that resulted in you having an invariant interface that wasn't of the right generic type for the situation you needed it in then you could have actually gotten answers that included different designs for how to solve that problem.  But you didn't ask that.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer You asked how to treat a set as if it were covariant.  You didn't use those words, but that's what you asked.  You want to be able to treat an `ISet<Whatever>` as if it's an `ISet<IWhatever>` without actually having multiple underlying sets.  *That's what generic covariance is*.  That's all that your question actually asks.  You provide no context at all for how you're using the interface, so there is no possibility for solving the problem you actually have because *you didn't explain what problem you actually have*.  You can't expect people to read your mind.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer They're not applicable.  Those questions are asking about situations where a question *describes a problem* and then asks a specific question related to that problem. You provided a specific question *with no context at all* and then posted an answer based on tons of information not presented in the question, and without so much as addressing the actual question asked. Again, if you wanted people to help you provide solutions to your actual problem, rather than answering the specific question that you asked, then at a minimum you need to *state your actual problem*.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer You're correct that your question doesn't make sense.  Asking how to do something that you know is impossible is indeed not a sensible thing to be asking.  Yet that's what you asked, so that's all that can be answered.  If you knew that you couldn't treat your set covariantly then you shouldn't have asked how to treat your set covariantly, you should have presented your actual problem, so that solutions that *wouldn't involve needing to treat your set covariantly* could be provided.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer I'm trying to help you understand what the problems with your question are, so that you can fix them when you ask future questions rather than repeating the same mistakes.  Clearly you have no interest in learning from your mistakes or improving, which is unfortunate.  Hopefully in the future you'll become humble enough to realize that there's actually the slightest of possibilities that you might not have actually done everything perfectly, and that there could be something for you to improve on, rather than demanding that answers read your mind in order to answer.

Comment: This Q&A has been linked as an example in [this meta discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344350/disruptive-answers).